# Android: animation doesn't end well

Tags: android, android-animation, textview, android-xml

In my app I have this animation in xml file for a textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="1"/>

</set>
```

but when the textview finish its animation, it return visible with alpha 1 and I want that it remains invisible with alpha 0.
What is wrong?

Comment: Well this animation is doing exactly what you have asked it too... fromAlpha 0.0 - toAlpha 1.0 ??

Comment: And what can I do to have at end animation alpha 0.0?

Comment: There is a reverse in there so they are right to expect it to end at 0

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Android gets a little fussy about XML vs. programatically setting things. I tested with your method and I got alpha of 0.0 at the end when I programatically set the fill after. So whereever you intialize your animation do: animationName.setFillAfter(true);  instead of having it in the XML.

Comment: I solved removing the Textview in the animationlistener at the end of animation... so it works fine and I'm happy :-)